# Playing music error and relative pathing

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm trying to play an mp3 in my app, and after a ton of research, I still can't figure out how to do relative pathing or even getting the music to play with absolute pathing. This is what I have:

```
//set music
NSError *error;
if (songChosen == 0)
{
    soundPath = @"/Users/aeubanks/Desktop/XCode Stuff/Apps/Game-Storyboard/Game-Storyboard/Amalgamation.mp3";
}
else if (songChosen == 1)
{
    soundPath = @"/Users/aeubanks/Desktop/XCode Stuff/Apps/Game-Storyboard/Game-Storyboard/BUTTERFLY.mp3";
}
audio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundPath] error:&error];
if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:soundPath] == NO)
{
    NSLog(@"No File");
}

else
{
    NSLog(@"Yes File");
}

if(error != nil)
{
    NSLog(@"%@", error);
}
[audio prepareToPlay];
```

The NSLog says this (be prepared):

> 2012-08-04 15:52:02.415 Game-Storyboard[8430:10703] Yes File
>
> 2012-08-04 15:52:02.473 Game-Storyboard[8430:12303] Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/AudioIPCDriver.kext/Contents/Resources/AudioIPCPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AudioIPCPlugIn:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AudioIPCDriver.kext/Contents/Resources/AudioIPCPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AudioIPCPlugIn, 262): Symbol not found: __*CFObjCIsCollectable
>     Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
>     Expected in: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
>    in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
>   2012-08-04 15:52:02.486 Game-Storyboard[8430:12303] Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/AudioIPCDriver.kext/Contents/Resources/AudioIPCPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AudioIPCPlugIn:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AudioIPCDriver.kext/Contents/Resources/AudioIPCPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AudioIPCPlugIn, 262): Symbol not found: _*_CFObjCIsCollectable
>     Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
>     Expected in: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
>    in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
>   2012-08-04 15:52:02.525 Game-Storyboard[8430:12303] Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn, 262): Symbol not found: __*CFObjCIsCollectable
>     Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
>     Expected in: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
>    in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
>   2012-08-04 15:52:02.546 Game-Storyboard[8430:12303] Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn, 262): Symbol not found: _*_CFObjCIsCollectable
>     Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
>     Expected in: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
>    in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
>   2012-08-04 15:52:02.570 Game-Storyboard[8430:12303] Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn, 262): Symbol not found: __*CFObjCIsCollectable
>     Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
>     Expected in: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
>    in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
>   2012-08-04 15:52:02.582 Game-Storyboard[8430:12303] Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn, 262): Symbol not found: _*_CFObjCIsCollectable
>     Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
>     Expected in: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
>    in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security

I have also tried setting soundPath to @"BUTTERFLY.mp3"/@"Amalgamation.mp3" as well as @"Game-Storyboard/BUTTERFLY.mp3"/@"Game-Storyboard/Amalgamation.mp3", and I get this:

> 2012-08-04 15:58:55.763 Game-Storyboard[8470:10703] No File
>
> 2012-08-04 15:58:55.767 Game-Storyboard[8470:10703] Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-43 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -43.)"

I have no idea what all this means, so I would appreciate some help to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this (here's a snippet):

```
if (songChosen == 0)
{
    NSString *soundFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Amalgamation" ofType:@"mp3"]
    NSURL *soundFileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath: soundFilePath];
    NSError *error;
    AVAudioPlayer *aPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFileURL error:&error];
}
```

I'd also suggest reading up on bundles.

Comment: I assume you're working in the simulator?  There is a known bug with that error - the main question is if the sound actually plays anyway.